# Using keras neural network in function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to implement an algorithm from a paper, using keras, where they train a neural network to approximate a mathematical function f(x) with limited amount of data points. I want the input of the neural network to be x and the output in the form of f(x) = 1 + xN(x), where N(x) is the value from the final dense layer.

I know how to make it work for output f(x) = N(x) but I just don't know how to adjust the network for f(x) = 1 + xN(x). Can someone help me?

This is my current code

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Add, Multiply
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import time

def f(x):
    return x**2

Xtrain = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
ytrain = np.array([f(x) for x in Xtrain])

X = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
y = np.array([f(x) for x in X])

input = Input(shape=(1,))
init = np.ones(shape=(10, 1))
init = K.variable(init)
hidden = input
hidden = Dense(8, activation='relu')(hidden)
out = Dense(1, activation='linear')(hidden)

out = Add()([init, Multiply()([out, input])])

model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=out)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="adam")

tic = time.perf_counter()
model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=1000, verbose=1)
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Training time: {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")

prediction = model.predict(X)
prediction = prediction.reshape((100,))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(X, y, color='red', label='Analytical solution')
plt.plot(X, prediction, color='black', label = 'Prediction')
plt.scatter(Xtrain, ytrain, color='blue', label='Training points')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.tight_layout()
```

which crashes at line

```
out = Add()([init, Multiply()([out, input])])
```

Answer (score 0):

The Add layer is working between two layers and between a layer and a number/ndarray.

you can just use it like this:

```
init=np.ones(shape=(10, 1))

inp = Input(shape=(1,))
hidden = Dense(8, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(1, activation='linear')(hidden)
mul=Multiply()([out, inp])
out = Add()([init, mul])
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="adam")
```

I checked it and it worked.

by the way, `input` is a builtin function, I don't recommend  to use it unless you want to use it.

Comment: I tried to run your code but I got the following ValueError.

ValueError: Layer add_57 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. Full input: [array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]]), <tf.Tensor 'multiply_66/mul:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Comment: you are right, it works with `import tensorflow.keras` just replace all of your imports.
also the shape of the test set `X` was wrong , and not match the `Xtrain` shape.
here is link to a working code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nfW30GsVqNVejJ_ZxOB1-3smGK3AtJao?usp=sharing